# Universal cover of figure eight is simply connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I've been going through Viro's Topology book and I'm stuck at the universal cover of figure eight($ \mathbb{F}(a,b)$ is a free group generated by 2 elements).

[image: Definition of K object]
[image: Universal cover of figure eight]

I can imagine the universal cover of figure eight -- that is simply the Cayley graph of $F_2$ and it's clear that it is simply connected -- but I can't prove that strictly: i.e. I don't clearly understand how to construct a path between the points to shown the above task **35.P.**. Furthermore I can't 'see' how to prove **35.Q.**.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: nice image as an infinite tree, every vertex valence four https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(topology)   as such it fits into the Poincare disc model of the hyperbolic plane; they adjust the figure to get more of a square outcome.

Comment: Since not everyone has access to this book, you should include definitions of $K$ and $\mathbb{F}(a, b)$, $U^+, U^-$, etc. Your question should ideally be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: As $F_2$ has no nontrivial relations, its Cayley graph is a tree. As a tree has no cycles, it also has no nontrivial loops I.e a loop on a Cayley graph is the same thing as a nontrivial relation in the group.

Comment: @William I added additional explanations.

Comment: Let me ask: how good is your understanding of quotient spaces and quotient maps? The reason I ask is because the answers to your questions about how to see, or to prove rigorously, that certain functions involving this example are actually continuous is to use the tools of quotients.

Comment: Well I don't think I can estimate myself like this, but seems not so good as I thought. 
I understand that when $X$ is created we got neighborhoods for the endpoints $U$ and $V$. By this action we 'extend' path which was only on $K$ onto $X$: $F_2$ helps us to consider as much $K$-copies as we want in order to describe loops in figure eight. 
But this thoughts are like on level of 'feelings' rather than on level of 'rigor stuff'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words:[image]

On the top left: the figure-eight space, with two generators $a, b$ for its fundamental group labeled. Top right: the universal cover $\Bbb{F}(a, b)$ with the lifts of $a, b$ labeled. Middle bottom: the same universal cover with some other elements of the fundamental group labeled. $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ represent going around the pictured loops in the opposite direction.

You can clearly see that in this picture, if I start at any element $x \in \Bbb{F}(a, b)$:

- the multiplication $xa$ corresponds to a step *right* from $x$ in the Cayley graph
- the multiplication $xb$ corresponds to a step *up* from $x$ in the Cayley graph
- the multiplication $xa^{-1}$ corresponds to a step *left* from $x$ in the Cayley graph
- the multiplication $xb^{-1}$ corresponds to a step *down* from $x$ in the Cayley graph

This should be very helpful as you think about how to demonstrate path-connectedness of the universal cover--**if** path-connectedness isn't built into your definition of a covering space of a path-connected space. The universal cover is simply connected [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers), I believe?

Comment: I don't know if simple-connectivity is always taken as part of the definition, but I think in OP's case they're meant to establish simple-connectivity in order to verify that it is indeed the universal cover.

Comment: @William From the picture you can see this covering space is contractible, so in particular it's path-connected and simply connected.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is just like taken from my thoughts on it and put in a text form. But I still don't quite understand how not to 'see' this properties, but to prove it rigorously for a construction given in Viro's textbook.

Comment: @PaulSnopov In the textbook construction, each group element $K \times \{ g \}$ is attached to four other copies $K \times \{ ga \},$ $K \times \{ gb \},$ $K \times \{ ga^{-1} \},$ and $K \times \{ gb^{-1} \},$ making it easy to demonstrate path-connectedness from there. Simply connectedness comes from the fact that every closed loop in the constructed universal cover with basepoint $\{ e \}$ comes from a sequence of group elements that come back to the identity, which if not null-homotopic would force there to be nontrivial relations in $\Bbb{F}(a, b)$, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You seem comfortable thinking about this construction as the Cayley graph of $\mathbb{F}(a, b)$, the free group on $\{a, b\}$, so I will hint at arguments you can make in terms of that. (I will be slightly sloppy about distinguishing a graph as formal data vs its geometric realization as a topological space.)

**Path-connected:** Every Cayley graph is path-connected as a topological space. For a hint as to how to prove this rigorously, note that if a group $G$ has generating set $S$ then by definition every element $g$ can be written (possibly non-uniquely) as a composition $s_1^{\epsilon_1}s_2^{\epsilon_2}s_3^{\epsilon_3}\dots s_n^{\epsilon_n}$ for $s_i \in S$ and $\epsilon_i \in \{-1, 1\}$. For the vertex $v[g]$ corresponding to $g$ in a Cayley graph $\Gamma(G, S)$, there is a (topological) path from the vertex $v[e]$, the vertex corresponding to the identity element, to $v[g]$ through the vertices $v[s_1^{\epsilon_1}]$, $v[s_1^{\epsilon_1}s_2^{\epsilon_2}]$, $v[s_1^{\epsilon_1}s_2^{\epsilon_2}s_3^{\epsilon_3}]$, etc., where whenever you have $\epsilon_i = -1$ you have to travel backwards along an edge in the directed graph.

*Aside:* As a directed graph the Cayley graph is frequently not path connected. For example if $F$ is a free group on $S$ and $s\in S$ then there is no directed path from $v[e]$ to $v[s^{-1}]$ in the Cayley graph $\Gamma(F, S)$, even though there is one from $v[s^{-1}]$ to $v[e]$.

**Simply-connected:** It is a fact that an undirected graph is simply-connected iff it is a tree. Show that if $\Gamma(G, S)$ (considered as an undirected graph) is not a tree then $G$ has a non-trivial relation in terms of $S$, or in other words if $F$ is a free group on $S$ then $\Gamma(F, S)$ is a tree.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've been thinking like that for a while(e.g. I was going to use the fact you mentioned above to prove simply connectedness), but as far as I find it obvious in some sense, I don't understand how to strictly write down the topological path between those vertices you mentioned earlier: i.e. I don't 'see' how this 'path' is going to be continuous.

Comment: My path is induced by a sequence of edges in the graph, as sequential pairs of vertices in the list I gave are connected by an edge (though the "direction" of the edge might be backwards) by construction. If you have a sequence of edges $e_1,\dots, e_k$ in a graph $G$, represented by continuous embeddings $e_i\colon [0,1]\to G$ such that $e_i(1) = e_{i+1}(0)$ for $1\leq i < k$, we can define a path $\gamma\colon [0,1] \to G$ from $e_1(0)$ to $e_k(1)$ by $\gamma(t) = e_i(kt - i +1)$ if $t\in [\frac{i-1}{k}, \frac{i}{k}]$, which is well-defined by assumption and continuous by the Glueing Lemma.

Comment: In order to be fully rigorous, you need to keep three distinct (but related) concepts straight in your mind: a directed graph $G$ has an induced undirected graph $\bar{G}$ (by just forgetting direction), and a geometric realization $|G|$ as a topological space. Strictly speaking the space being constructed here isn't THE Cayley graph, but its geometric realization. Maybe for clarity I should have introduced different notations from the start.

Comment: Oh, well, now I see, before I wasn't even considering edges of Cayley graph for some reason, and this is why I couldn't imagine continuous map -- I was thinking just about $F_2$ as a discrete top. space, and if I could make a path from, say, $e \in F_2$ to some $g$, I would get that $I$ is not a connected. But since I have $X$ i.e. $(K \cross F_2 )/ \sim$ I can consider 'edges' between 'vertices' that are associated with elements of $F_2$. Did I get this, not really tough part, correct, didn't I?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T$ be the Cayley graph of $G=\mathbb F(a,b)$ with respect to $S=\{a,b\}$.

Let us first show that $T$ is path-connected.
Let $u,v\in G$ and let $w=u^{-1}v$. Suppose $w=s_1s_2\ldots s_n$ where the $s_i$'s are in $S$. Then we get a path from $u$ to $v$ whose vertices are $u$, $us_1$, $us_1s_2$, $\ldots$, $us_1s_2\ldots s_n=uu^{-1}v=v$.

The same argument shows that if $S$ is a generating set for a group $G$, then the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to $S$ is connected. We now show that $T$ is simply-connected.

We define a sequence of trees $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ as follows.

Let $T_0$ be the tree with a single vertex corresponding to the identity element $e$.
Let $T_1$ be the tree with four edges whose leaves correspond to the words of length 1, namely $a,b,a^{-1},b^{-1}$.
Let $T_2$ be the tree whose leaves correspond to the words of length 2.
Let $T_n$ be the tree whose leaves correspond to the words of length $n$.

The interiors of the $T_n$'s give an increasing open cover of $T$.
As the image of any loop in $T$ is a compact subset of $T$, it is contained in some $T_n$.
As $T_n$ is a tree, it is a simply-connected subset of $T$.

Hence, it follows that $T$ is simply-connected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1945671)

Comment: Ok, I missed that he wants to show that T is path-connected also.

Comment: Please edit in more information so that this post _answers_ the question, or at least helps the OP in a significant part of the question.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope that this helps. : )